# Passing parameter to php page with append the value in the URL

Tags: php, html

Let’s say this is my form field code:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
<input type="text" size="25" name="username" />
<input type="text" size="25" name="password" />
</form>
```

These two input boxes allow users to enter information. At **process.php**, you can grab the variables in the same way:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

now i want open page "process.php" directly with passing parameters

i use this link

> localhost/process.php?username=ahmed&password=123456

not working ,i know if use **$_GET** will work well

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
```

but i want use **$_POST**

what i will to open this page with this way ???

Answer (score 2):

`$_REQUEST`. It's basically a merge of `$_POST`, `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, you should be able to use $_REQUEST['username'] and $_REQUEST['password']

I'd recommend against it for security reasons if it's going anywhere near a database, but that will allow you to use POST or GET.

Answer (score 0):

You can only pass GET parameters in the URL. To send POST data directly, you would want to use something like CURL to format your request properly to include variables as POST data.